# primality testing using a modified Fermat test

Tags: number-theory

Is the following valid:

$$n>1 \textrm{ is prime} \longleftrightarrow\forall a\in \{1,...,n-1\}\:a^{n-1}\equiv1\mod{n}$$
proof: If n is prime use FLT. If n is not prime then n has a prime factor p

notice we bypass the carmichael  difficulty. But p=? you try with various a=(product of) primes

Comment: much of my post vanished, namely the rest of the proof: p<n and when a=p we get p^(n-1)- Kn can't =1 because p divides p^(n-1) -Kn but p does not divide 1

Comment: Please [edit] the question yourself. Also, [please use MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), it'll make your question much more clear.

Comment: You mention "the [C]armichael difficulty", which alludes the fact that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for all $a$ *coprime* to $n$ for certain composite numbers $n$.  By requiring the congruence for all $1\le a \le n-1$ you do avoid this possibility of composite $n$ simply because when $a\mid n$, no positive power of $a$ modulo $n$ can be a unit.  Simply sticking a question mark in the post doesn't give the Readers enough information to deduce what you want to ask.

Comment: The claim is true , but the method is useless in practice because we have to check $n-1$ congruences.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall a\in \{1,...,n-1\}\:a^{n-1}\equiv1\bmod{n}$ implies $\forall a\in \{1,...,n-1\}\:\gcd(a,n)=1$ and this is equivalent to $n$ is prime.